# Javascript doesn't work inside <head> or <body> tags

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I tried putting this code:

```
<script>
    function myfunc()
    {
        var xmlhttp;

        if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        else
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
            else
                alert("Something went wrong!");
        }

        var tbl = document.GetElementByID("tbl_users");
        var str="";

        var tid;
        var isActive;

        for(x=0; x=tbl.rows[x]; x++)
        {
            tid=0;
            isActive="true";

            if(tbl.cells[1].checked)
                tid=1;
            else
                tid=2;

            if(tbl.cells[6].checked)
                isActive="true";
            else
                isActive="false";

            str="uid="+tbl.cells[0].value+"&tid="+tid+"&firstName="tbl.cells[2].value+"&lastName="+tbl.cells[3].value+"&userName="+tbl.cells[4].value+"&passWord="+tbl.cells[5].value+"&isActive="+isActive;

            xmlhttp.open("POST", "save.php", true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlhttp.send(str);
        }
    }
</script>
```

...inside the  tags of a web page I'm making, as I only followed some tutorials which shows the same. Here's the code for my HTML:
    
    
        Users

```
    <!--JS codes above here-->
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <table align='center' border='1' name='tbl_users'>
            <tr>
                <td>UID</td>
                <td>Admin</td>
                <td>First Name</td>
                <td>Last Name</td>
                <td>Username</td>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td>Active</td>
            </tr>

            <?php
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($table))
            {
                echo "
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type='text' name='uid' value='".$row['uid']."' disabled/></td>";
                        if($row['tid'] == 1)
                            echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='tid' value='1' checked/></td>";
                        else
                            echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='tid' value='2'/></td>";
                echo "  <td><input type='text' name='firstName' value='".$row['firstName']."' /></td>
                        <td><input type='text' name='lastName' value='".$row['lastName']."' /></td>
                        <td><input type='text' name='userName' value='".$row['userName']."' /></td>
                        <td><input type='text' name='passWord' value='".$row['passWord']."'/></td>";
                        if($row['isActive'] == 0)
                            echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='isActive' value='true' checked/></td>";
                        else
                            echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='isActive' value='false'/></td>";

                echo "</tr>";
            }?>

        <tr>
            <td colspan='7' align='right'><input type='button' value="Save" onclick='myfunc()'/></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

Now, I've read possible solutions for that like:
- putting it inside a `$(document).ready()` call
- putting the JS code inside the  tag, just below the  closing tag

But still, it won't work.

I have tried simple JS codes like:

```
<script> function myfunc(){alert("hello world!");} </script>
```

...with the same solutions, and only the 2nd method worked for this.

Any idea?

Comment: add PHP and AJAX to the Question tags

Comment: Is anything outputted to the console?

Comment: first check JavaScript is enable or not in browser

Comment: `var tbl = document.GetElementByID("tbl_users");`A typo here: `GetElementByID` should be `getElementById()`

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? Have you set the breakpoint?

Comment: mysql_fetch_array($table) .You haven't initialised $table.No query has been set.

Comment: @chetanmehta, I do have a PHP code above the HTML to initialize that.

Comment: @NanheKumar, JS is enabled.

Comment: @JustinL., just the table retrieved from my database.

Comment: @ŁukaszLech, I'm trying to process data from the table whose data came from the database.

Comment: it should sounds obvious, but when you use $(document).ready() did you include the jquery?

Comment: You forgot the `<html>` tag and you forgot to open the `<head>` tag. A `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: @peorthyr, was wondering about that. I'm just learning JS, and jQuery is still on the list of to-learn. I didn't see any jQuery tags on the other questions like this one, that's why I didn't knew.

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs, not sure why it can't be seen in the codes above, but I've tried to edit the post and it was there, except the <!DOCTYPE HTML>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see at least two problems:

1. JavaScript is case-sensitive, and `var tbl = document.GetElementByID("tbl_users");` should be `var tbl = document.getElementById("tbl_users");` (note the `g` and `d` in `getElementById`).
2. In this line:

   ```
   str="uid="+tbl.cells[0].value+"&tid="+tid+"&firstName="tbl.cells[2].value+"&lastName="+tbl.cells[3].value+"&userName="+tbl.cells[4].value+"&passWord="+tbl.cells[5].value+"&isActive="+isActive;
   ```

   ...you're missing a `+` after `"&firstName="` and before `tbl.cells[2].value`. Your console should be telling you that you have an `Unexpected identifier`.

Comment: Did what you said, but my console still says this:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier update.php:77
Uncaught ReferenceError: myfunc is not defined

Comment: @MicoFrancisco: It should also be telling you you have an `Unexpected identifier`, see (the latest) #2 above. This is just basic debugging, look at the errors you get, look at the lines they're on, and it should be possible to figure them out. If you fix the above, that seems to be it for syntax errors, but I can't vouch for all the logic, I didn't check for logic errors.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, but I know basic debugging. I'm just trying to figure out why my function doesn't work, or can't be seen.

Comment: @MicoFrancisco: **Because it has a syntax error in it**. As I said, #2 above. When code in a code block has a syntax error in it, the functions it defines aren't defined.

Comment: I see. Sorry, was just starting to learn JS, alongside with PHP and AJAX, so wasn't really aware of that. I guess the problem is solved, but I still got a few more errors after solving that one, I can take this.

Answer (score 1):

The `for(x=0; x=tbl.rows[x]; x++)` should be `for(x=0; x<tbl.rows[x]; x++)`.

You need a comparison operator in the 2nd section.

Here is a clean up version.  Remember you should always use curly braces on the end of your if lines because the JS compiler likes to insert ; otherwise.

```
function myfunc() {
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        } else {
            alert("Something went wrong!");
        }
    }

    var tbl = document.getElementById("tbl_users");
    var str = "";

    var tid;
    var isActive;

    for (x = 0; x < tbl.rows[x]; x++) {
        tid = 0;
        isActive = "true";

        if (tbl.cells[1].checked) {
            tid = 1;
        } else {
            tid = 2;
        }

        if (tbl.cells[6].checked) {
            isActive = "true";
        } else {
            isActive = "false";
        }

        str = "uid=" + tbl.cells[0].value + "&tid=" + tid + "&firstName=" 
                + tbl.cells[2].value + "&lastName=" + tbl.cells[3].value + "&userName="
                + tbl.cells[4].value + "&passWord=" + tbl.cells[5].value
                + "&isActive=" + isActive;

        xmlhttp.open("POST", "save.php", true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good catch, but more likely it should be `x < tbl.rows.length`.

Comment: Good Point. That wouldn't get very far. :)

Comment: I stand corrected. I have an over blown view of JS from reading Douglas Crockford.  I may have mixed up exactly what the Automatic Semicolon Insertion (ASI) feature does.  After looking into it further, I agree with you.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @ Joshua: No worries. ASI is an abomination and a pain, no question. :-)